# UTC time for each pixel in a datacube

Tags: python, satellite-image

The [Sentinel-5P](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel-5_Precursor) satellite collects observations from space. It outputs the data as "image" files for each swath where each pixel refers to what it measured for that area, pixel-wise geotagged (I believe) and all.

For downloading, we can easily obtain the observations as a datacube using the [openeo Python client](https://open-eo.github.io/openeo-python-client/index.html):

```py
import openeo

connection = openeo.connect("openeo.dataspace.copernicus.eu")
connection.authenticate_oidc()

datacube = connection.load_collection(
    "SENTINEL_5P_L2",
    spatial_extent={"west": 5.14, "south": 51.17, "east": 5.17, "north": 51.19},
    temporal_extent=["2021-02-01", "2021-04-30"],
)
```

It is reported that only the date at which the entire swath started and ended is recorded, but not the timestamp for each pixel. **I want to approximate this by lerping between the start and end times based on how far the pixel is along the swath.** So, how do I even obtain the metadata for each pixel in the image?